# Set Environment var from headers response

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I'm executing a post call which returns a list of headers. One of those headers is called "Bunny-id" and returns a number. (Let's suppose Bunny-id --> 159).

I'm trying to take that number and paste it automatically to my environment..Environment var is already there and it's called "id_pratica_artoo", here's the code:

```
pm.test("set environment variable for chain", function() {
    var headerData = pm.response.headers;
    pm.environment.set('id_pratica_artoo', headerData.Bunny-id);
});
```

Executing the POST call with the above test gets me the following error:

> set environment variable for chain | ReferenceError: id is not defined

What am I missing?

Comment: what you are getting in `console.log(headerData)`?

Comment: @Div console.log(pm.response.headers) reports an array where the 6th is the information i want.
If, for example, i set as follows:

`pm.test("test", function() {
    var bunny_id = pm.response.headers[6];
    pm.environment.set('id_pratica_artoo', bunny_id)
    console.log(pm.response.headers[6]);
});`

Then, i get "null" on that console.log, as it was impossible to access that information into the array

Answer (score 0):

resolved by using the following:

```
pm.test("set environment variable for chain", function () {
pm.response.to.have.header('Bunny-id');
pm.environment.set('id_pratica_artoo', pm.response.headers.get('Bunny-id'));
```